# grails/gorm messages bundle

Tags: grails, message, bundle, grails-orm

Please help me with this thing. I'll be more specific this time, because i have already got an ansfor for this and cudnt get this to work. I have a class:

```
package aa1

class City {

    String name

    static constraints = {
        name(blank: false, nullable:false, unique: true, matches:"[a-zA-z ]+")
    }

    String toString(){
        name
    }
}
```

I want to make a customized error message for this. For that, i added in the messages.proprietis (because i didnt know what was the type of constraint syntax):

```
aa1.City.name.doesnt.match=Letters between a-z and spaces.
aa1.City.name.match=Letters between a-z and spaces.
aa1.City.name.matches=Letters between a-z and spaces.
```

All i get for the error message is:

```
Property [username] of class [class trafficmanfinal.User] with value ["] does not match the required pattern [[a-zA-z0-9]+]
```

I can't get this to work. And let me know if there is any list of customized error syntax to help me in the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
aa1.City.name.matches.invalid=the message
```

Comment: didnt work i dont know why.. it should work. other messages work and this one dont.

Comment: @john i updated my answer.  turns out in your other question, my answer is not correct.  you should take off the checkmark.

Comment: @john, i fixed the other answer ;)  But you should probably delete this question or the other.  Did what I have above work?  It should now.

Comment: ok so this one is confirmed and it is working - so solved. thank you very much